# analytical methods for crossover study that has an addition control group

Tags: mixed-model, control-group, crossover-study

I have a crossover study where patients perform a cognitive task (with two conditions) when their brain stimulation is switched on and then off. Using a mixed effects regression, I would ensure that the two task conditions are nested within on/off conditions, which are nested within patients.

However, I also wish to include a control group (who does not have the brain stimulation treatment) as a comparison. Is it reasonable in this situation to treat the three groups as between subjects groups (i.e., stimulation on, stimulation off, control group). Obviously they are not independent. Is there another way I should treat the control group in this analysis? I suppose the main contrast for this analysis will be the on vs control and off vs control? And to examine the on vs off I would use the analysis mentioned above?